# differentiate requests by device expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, user-agent

I'm using a simple expressJS app.

```js
server = app.listen(config.port, () => {
    logger.info(`Listening to port ${config.port}`);
  });
```

I am trying to differentiate whether multiple requests come from the same device or from a different devices. Is there a unique ID, or something that I can get from the `req` object in express ?

I tried to check User-Agent and IP address. But these are not unique to the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can using [node-machine-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-machine-id?activeTab=readme) library for getting device unique ID.

You can give caller machine ID into REST API call's header.
Can compare server's machine ID, to compare same or not.

If same, call from same device.

If not same, call from other device.

Demo server.js and clinet.js

server.js

```
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")
const machineId = require('node-machine-id')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

PORT = 3000
const serverDeviceId = machineId.machineIdSync({original: true});

app.get("/data", async (request, response) => {

    console.log(`request :${JSON.stringify(request.headers, null, 4)}`)
    let isSaveDevice = false;
    if (request.headers?.deviceid == serverDeviceId) {
        isSaveDevice = true;
    }
    return response.send({
        data: 'test data',
        callFrom: (isSaveDevice)? 'Same device' : 'Different Device',
        callerDeviceId: request.headers?.deviceid,
        serverDeviceId: serverDeviceId
    })
})

// start express server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on :${PORT}`)
})
```

client.js

```
const axios = require('axios')
const machineId = require('node-machine-id');

const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const id = machineId.machineIdSync({original: true});
        const resp = await axios.get(
            url = 'http://localhost:3000/data',
            config = {
                headers : {'deviceid': `${id}`}
            }
        );
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.data, null, 4));
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

getData();
```

Install dependencies

```
npm install express cors node-machine-id axios
```

Running server

```
node server.js
```

Running Client

```
node client.js
```

Result in client side

```
$ node client
{
    "data": "test data",
    "callFrom": "Same device",
    "callerDeviceId": "42543e29ccb7471bba0760b328d4a41f",
    "serverDeviceId": "42543e29ccb7471bba0760b328d4a41f"
}
```

Result in server side

```
$ node server.js
Listening on :3000
request :{
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "deviceid": "42543e29ccb7471bba0760b328d4a41f",
    "user-agent": "axios/1.4.0",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br",
    "host": "localhost:3000",
    "connection": "keep-alive"
}
```

#### Update

remote-client.js

```js
const axios = require('axios')

const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get(
            url = 'http://localhost:3000/data',
        );
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.data, null, 4));
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

getData();
```

Result in server

```
request :{
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "user-agent": "axios/1.4.0",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br",
    "host": "localhost:3000",
    "connection": "keep-alive"
}
```

Result in remote client

```
{
    "data": "test data",
    "callFrom": "Different Device",
    "serverDeviceId": "42543e29ccb7471bba0760b328d4a41f"
}
```

The server can detect call from local or remote.
the device ID is optional data.

```
request.headers?.deviceid
```

Comment: Unfortunately. I don't have access to the client from which they will be sending the request. (It will be a direct GET request from their browser). I need a solution that only uses the server side.

Comment: I updated my answer. The device ID is optional so remote client just regular API call without device ID. the server can detect it's data include in header or not. If include in header, it means call from local. If not include, it means remote call.

Comment: I am not able to set headers from the client side, as I already told you. 
the request will be done by users just navigating to the URL using their regular browser. Like chrome or safari.

Comment: Two situation from same device(you can add header) or from a different devices (can't add header). Is is true or not? My point is the save device (in local) able to set header. it can makes a difference between client site and local site.